# JS- Input type file firing change evt when there is no change

Tags: javascript

Hi I have been working on a script to upload files with the same input, a problem emerges when I follow the next steps:

1. Select a file [It's uploaded as soon as change evt fires using ajax]
2. Click select file
3. Cancel without selecting any file

The problem is that text is alerted when I think it's not necessary

Code:

```
<form parameters="values...">
    <input type="file" id="file"/>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#file").on("change", function () { 
            let input = this;
            if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
                //upload
            }else {
                alert("Error: Incompatible browser");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The alert is never done unless there is no browser compatibility but this "BUG" makes the alert appear

Comment: Just FYI, `$(this)[0]` can just be `this`...

Comment: Oh thanks, I never thought about it, useful knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chrome *feature*, where when the user clicks *"Cancel"* it actually clears the input from what has been set before.
IMO, a *"Clear"* button would have make more sense, but since the file-picking UI is the one of the OS, I guess they couldn't change it.

But anyway, your check for incompatible browsers just needs to be

```
// in onchange
if(input.files){
```

or even better

```
// before assigning the change handler
if('FileList' in window){
```

Since browsers that don't support `<input type="file">` wont set neither the `input.files`, nor will they have the FileList constructor.

Comment: Well, You have cleared a lot of things, I think I'll rather use your code, I can't accept your answer but it has been very helpful so I'll upvote it.

Comment: @HeribertoJuárez Why can't you accept it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Well It doesn't really solves my problem but thinking it better I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @HeribertoJuárez if you need more info / clarification, feel free to ask. I though this simple change in your code would solve your problem.

Comment: I made the change but the same problem is caused, I thought about a kind of complex solution, thanks anyway, I'll try to implement a solution.

Comment: Just for everyone's knowledge Changing input.files for 'FileList' in window solves the problem, In my case the message would still be alerted because I was using a function inside my uploading process that still used input.files, so thanks a lot and sorry for the misunderstanding.